# I need help improving an indicator I use regularly

Tags: pine-script

Would anyone be willing to help me rebuild an indicator that I use regularly. The indicator is called False breakout, and gives a signal and a line to the left on the candle on which it was created.
I would like to modify it so that the line extends to the right until the price (candle) reaches that line again, and then the line stops.
Thanks and greetings to all the good people here.

I don't know how to code in pine scrip, and I tried with the help of AI, but it seems that AI can't do it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include your source code as a working [mcve], which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.